# email confirmation link should expire after particular time period in servlets?

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners

Little bit confused on how to implement the expiry timeout to email confirmation link..

As i'm fresher can you please help me in what way can we implement?

When i browsed came through the concept listeners,sessions

what is the best approach to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the confirmation token in the db against the userid.

Schedule a db job that will delete the token after specific time if the token is not used.

Comment: okay I have generated one random number for that I should keep expiry is dat? in sessions we can use setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60);

Comment: Storing it to session will not do. Store it into database. Create a job in the database that will clear the token when the scheduled job will run if the token not used

Comment: Iam storing to a file not DB.Anyway it has to work..!! Let me try

Comment: All the best :)